# Workmanager shuts down when app is killed in android

Tags: android

I use AlarmManager from the WorkManager.
When the App is foregrounded, AlarmManager works correctly.
But when the App is killed(turn off the swipe by viewing the latest app), WorkManager also is killed.

Why does workmanager die?
I want WorkManager similar to Immortal Service.
Because I'm making alarmApp

**MainActivity.class onCreate**

```
WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class).build();
workManager.enqueue(workRequest);
```

**MyWorker.class**

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {
Context context;
Thread thread;

public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(context, workerParams);
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    Log.d("1106", "MyWorker_doWork()");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    Log.d("1106", "" + calendar.getTime());

    Intent notiIntent = new Intent(context, NotiReceiver.class);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    calendar.set(2020, 10, 06, 06, 25, 0);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, notiIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);

    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int cnt = 0;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("1106", cnt++ + "");
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    return Result.success();
}
```

}